# Is there a simple way to use Underscorejs to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object, having key and values.  I'd like to pick the object and call the appropriate function from the key:

```
var requireViews = {
            "breadCrumbView": true,
            "headerView": false,
            "footerView": false
        };

var that = this;

    _.each(requireViews, function(value, key){
                    if(value){ //if true?
                        if(_.functions(that, key)) that[key](); //checking is that function, and calling the function
                    }
                })
```

Is it ok or can we minimize it further?

Comment: What else is `requireViews` used for? Could you add more context to your question?

Comment: from the requireViews, I am picking what are all the views has to render. I will override this object from other function to. and 'that' is this here. so I am finding whether the 'that' has that function(ex: breadCrumbView) the I am calling the same. - any more clarification required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `filterObject` mixin (this is the one I usually use), it will be easy

```
_.mixin({
    filterObject: function(obj, predicate, context) {
        return _.reduce(obj, function(memo, val, key) {
            if (predicate.call(context, val, key, memo)) memo[key] = val;
            return memo;
        }, {});
    }
});
```

Now its simple and elegant :)

```
_.invoke(this, _.values(_.filterObject(requireViews, Boolean)));
```

If you like underscores you can use the ridiculous algorithm below (don't do it!)

```
_.invoke(this, _.map(_.filter(_.pairs(requireViews), _.partial(_.every, _, Boolean)), _.first))
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd skip underscore for this, and just do

```
for(var func in requireViews) {
  if(requireViews[func] && typeof this[func] === 'function') {
    this[func]();
  }
}
```

Otherwise, there are many different ways to go about it.

Here's a needlessly complex one, for instance:

```
var target = this;
_.chain(requireViews)
  .keys()
  .filter(function (func) { return requireViews[func] })
  .intersection(_.functions(this))
  .each(function (func) { target[func]() });
```